Migrate ADO project from to another New Project in Same Organisation
We are looking to migrate our current ADO project, including, board, repo, pipeline etc from our current project to New Project. This is to enable Epics. Is there a way to to move using any tools or Rest API.
We are Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1 (AzureDevOpsServer_20231006.1)
Thanks
Sunil Bindra
Tried creating new project

Would you please help clarify what you mean by saying "This is to enable Epics."? Do you want to use different boards process?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Currently there is no tool or API that can directly migrate the entire project. You need to separately migrate the repo, work item, pipeline, etc.

Migrate Work Items, TestPlans & Suits, Teams, Shared Queries, Pipelines, & Processes
You can use this extension in the Marketplace: Migration Tools for Azure DevOps.

Migrate Repo
Please follow the steps from this doc Clone an existing Git repo to clone the repos from one project and import to another.


There is already a feature request make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections asking for project migration. You can follow it for the update.
